# Sending non-string argument in a POST request to a Tornado server

Tags: python, post, tornado

In the `post` method of a RequestHandler in Tornado, `self.get_argument(arg, None)` gets the value of `arg` contained in the request.

All the examples I've seen return a string as value, which makes me wonder if we can send data other than strings in a POST request.

The specific use case I am interested in: I have a form with multiple fields on the page, and I want to **pack a subset of its fields together in a single argument** in the POST request to the server, something like

```
packed = self.get_argument('packed_arg', None)
arg1 = packed['arg1']
arg2 = packed['arg2']
...
```

while the rest of the fields are still of individual arguments. So far I'm thinking data structure similar to a `dict` (maybe JSON?) for this packed argument, is this feasible?

Comment: Why not send them as separate POST parameters?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, the set of fields to be packed into a single argument is not fixed. Instead, different fields will be packed depending on some other fixed field(s) on the form. I intend to group them together under the name of 'custom parameters'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON will fit well for your purposes.

Do something like this, on client side:

```
var data = {'packed_arg':get_form_args(); }
```

Function `get_form_args()` is abstraction. You can implement it any way. Javascript objects are JSONs by default. 
So on client side you must create dictionary from form fields. 
Think this way:

```
var data = {};
var names_to_pack = ['packed1', 'packed2']
$(form).find('input, select').each(function (i, x) {
    var name = $(x).attr('name')
    if(names_to_pack.indexOf(name) != -1) { 
        if(!data.packed) {
            data.packed = {};  
        }
        data['packed'][name] = $(x).val(); 
    } else { 
        data[name] = $(x).val(); 
    }
});
$.post('/', data);
```

And then on server side:

```
raw_packed = self.get_argument('packed_arg', None)
packed = {}
if raw_packed: 
    packed = tornado.escape.json_decode(raw_packed)
arg1 = packed.get('arg1')
arg2 = packed.get('arg2')
```

Also you can access all POST args in `self.request.arguments`.

Comment: on the client side, how do I POST other data (i.e. other fields on the form) together with this `packed_arg`? Thanks.

Comment: and I guess the function `get_form_args()` on the client side returns a dictionary?